# priority of outlook email inbox rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

what if an email correctly hits two rules.

for example:

1. Rule 1: Email from my boss goes into Important
2. Rule 2: Email with subject of "Summer" goes into deleted items

what if my boss sends me an email with the subject of "Summer" ?

what is the ordering of rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you setup the rule locate the "Stop processing more rules" option on the "What do you want to do with the message?" page of the rule setup wizard and select it.  This will stop Outlook from processing any more rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can move "up" and "down" rules among the listing but I don't think this will have any effect on the issue you're having.

I tested it out as the same way you did:

Rule #1: Move email to a folder coming from person X.

Rule #2: Delete email with subject: Summer

I sent an email to myself so I thought the mail would be moved before deleted or even better, won't be deleted...

The email has been deleted automatically...

You can set exceptions as the end of the rules properties. By example: You can set that rule so when you receive an email with Summer as subject, sent from "Boss" this mail won't be deleted.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid deleting your boss email, for rule 2 you can add **except if from people or distribution list** and type your boss email address.

Comment: you can also select to stop processing more rules for rule 1. Outlook processes rules one by one

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use `stop processing more rules` option on the most specific/high priority rules.

*Ref: [manage email using rules at Outlook](https://www.wikihow.com/Manage-Email-Using-Microsoft-Outlook-Rules)*

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please elaborate on your answer. While you are citing a link which probably has the answer, links can become broken, thus making your answer useless.